# k8s Pv is not created

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I want to create PV&PVC and the PV is not created , can you please advice what am I doing wrong?

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: my-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: io1
  iopsPerGB: "100"
  fsType: ext4
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc
  namespace: myns
spec:
  storageClassName: io1
  volumeName: my-sc
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

The issue is that the PV is not created...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to provide the `kubectl events` output, and probably logs from the cluster.  But it's probably IAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your StorageClass is named `my-sc`

Your PersistentVolumeClaim has its `spec.storageClassName` set to `io1`.

It should match an existing StorageClass name (`my-sc`).

You should delete your PVC, and re-create it with the proper storageClassName.